# How to find model class name from its value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, has-and-belongs-to-many

i have an object **resource** with attachments as its associated object. When i call **resource.attachments** its showing blank array [] that means resource have no attachments, but i want to get object or classname of attachments. Note that attachment is not a nested resource of **resource** class but connected through habtm association.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [.name](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#M001699) on the object's class:

```
resource.attachments[n].class.name
```

Note that this is pure ruby and has nothing related to rails and habtm.

By the way you can't call .class.name on your empty array, you have to have some objects in.

Comment: But resource.attachments returns []  and resource.attachments.class returns Array

Comment: I can't get it... if there is no attachments, the type of what are you looking for ? And if each resource can only have one type of attachment, you have no need to get this type dynamically... Just store it somewhere in a field of `Resource`, then get it when you read your resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveRecord::Reflection like this to retrieve associations:

```
 Resource.reflect_on_all_associations
```

OR

```
 Resource.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_and_belongs_to_many)
```

To get all associated class names:

```
 Resource.reflect_on_all_associations.collect!(&:name)
```

Cheers.